# Why is Q/nF equivalent to the amount of substance in electrolysis?

Tags: electrolysis

I am told that

$$Q = nF$$

where $Q$ is the quantity of current, $n$ is the amount of electrons and $F$ is Faraday's constant. Since Faraday's constant is the charge carried by 1 mol of electrons, multiplying it by the amount of electrons to give the total charge makes perfect sense. But why does dividing $Q$ by $nF$ gives the amount of substance? Won't the answer just be 1 for all possible values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a general electrolytic reaction,

$$\ce{M^{n+} + $n$ e^- -> M}$$

where $n$ moles of electrons are consumed in depositing **1 mole** of substance ($n$ is also known as $n$-factor). So, for $x$ moles of substance, $nx$ moles of electrons would be consumed. Therefore,

$$Q = nxF,$$

dividing by $nF$ on both sides, we have

$$\frac{Q}{nF} = x,$$

which is the amount of substance.

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. Thank you!

Comment: @rv7 Please visit [this page](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [this page](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/) and [this one](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/) on how to format your future posts better with MathJax and Markdown.

Comment: @andselisk: Thanks for the links. I'll take care of that next time.

Comment: Often, $z$ is used for the stoichiometric factor, and $n$ for the amount of substance, so it becomes $n = \frac{Q}{z F}$, see e.g. https://www.bipm.org/utils/en/pdf/SIApp2_mol_en.pdf @rv7